# Set maxIdleTime on HttpClient for all requests from Spring Security -> OAuth2/OIDC server

Tags: spring-security

I have an existing Spring app that's already using Spring Security to authenticate against an OpenID Connect auth server. After authentication, it redirects back to our Spring app as it should, but sometimes (maybe 10% of the time) it displays an error while posting the auth code to get the JWT. This is because NLB on the way to the server (code/infra we don't control) has already shut down the persistent connections after being idle a few minutes:

```
org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClientRequestException: Connection prematurely closed BEFORE response
    ...
    *__checkpoint ⇢ Request to POST https://<myServer>/<myRealmPath>/protocol/openid-connect/token [DefaultWebClient]
```

We have 2 other areas that make requests to this auth server, and we've solved the problem in those areas by setting a maxIdleTime. In those scenarios it's easy to provide a customized reactor-netty HttpClient, but this Spring Security flow is proving more difficult. Specifically, we've managed to apply the fix in that situation via this bean:

```
ReactiveOAuth2AccessTokenResponseClient<OAuth2AuthorizationCodeGrantRequest> authorizationCodeTokenResponseClient() { ... }
```

However, now we get a similar error from a subsequent step:

```
org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClientRequestException: Connection prematurely closed BEFORE response
    ...
    *__checkpoint ⇢ Request to GET https://<myServer>/<myRealmPath>/protocol/openid-connect/userinfo [DefaultWebClient]
```

This all seems like quite the maze to go through. **Is there a way to customize the WebClient or its HttpClient for *all* requests from Spring Security to the auth server?**